# draw a polygon with fabric.js framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

i'm trying to draw a free polygon using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/e5Xth/3/

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
        if (lines[0] !== null && drawingObject.type == "roof") {
            setStartingPoint(options);
            lines[lineCounter - 1].set({
                x2: x,
                y2: y
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    });
```

In this jsfiddle works perfectly but using the same code on my page, the lines are not drawn polygon where I "really drawing". they are "born" all of the top left corner, but when I click to form the polygon it draws correctly.

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the mouse down event, you are setting the orginx and originy which is taken to the right top corner. I have given below the updated code.

```
function mousedown(event) {
                    setStartingPoint(event);
                    var points = [x, y, x, y];
                    var line = new fabric.Line(points, {
                        left: x,
                        top: y,
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                        selectable: false,
                        stroke: '#40648E'
                    });
                    lines.push(line);
                    canvas.add(lines[lineCounter]);
                    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
                        left: x-2.5,
                        top: y-2.5,
                        width: 5,
                        height: 5,
                        fill: '#fff',
                        stroke: '#000',
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        selectable: false
                    });
                    canvas.add(rect);
                    lineCounter++;
                }
            }

 function mousemove(event) {
                    canvas.defaultCursor = "crosshair";
                    if (lines[0] !== null) {
                        setStartingPoint(event);
                        if (lines[lineCounter - 1] != null) {
                            lines[lineCounter - 1].set({
                                "x2": x,
                                "y2": y
                            });
                        }
                        canvas.renderAll();
                    }
                }
```